# Login into google account on Iphone 5s not possible

Tags: iphone, gmail, login, google

About a month ago my Iphone 5s updated and afterwards I couldn't log in to my google account on my Iphone, when I try to log in from any other device it works completely fine. Neither in the youtube app nor when I try to log in to my gmail account in the safari browser. I always get following message:

[image]

When I click on next following instructions are shown:

[image]

I did everything as told and it didn't change. I searched google, and nothing could help me. I uninstalled the youtube app, reinstalled it, still no changes.

The only intresting fact is, that I am logged in to my gmail account in native mail app and this works completely fine.

I could try to reset the whole Iphone, but I would prefer to find a better solution than that.

Comment: Are you using any content blockers?  Can you log into that account from a different iPhone?

Comment: No I am not, and I can log in from an Iphone 6

Comment: Looks like an in-app web browser in that image. Which app? Try using plain old safari to sign in?

Comment: Youtube app, same thing in safari